# Software UART of 2 PICs with diffrerent clock frequency

Tags: pic

Is it possible to communicate the 2 PICs with different clock frequency via software UART? By the way I'm using 2 PIC16f877a. One is connected to PC use 16mhz oscillator and the other one is using 4 mhz oscillator. Im using mikroC compiler for this. Thank you.

Comment: As long as they have the same Baud rate, it should be fine.

Comment: Yes, i use the same baud rate for the two PIC and it works perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the respective clocks can be divided down in a readily available process to the targeted baud rate withing the acceptable tolerance for UART communication.  My suspicion is that this is possible in many cases, but not all cases.  Because your clocks differ by a small power of two, I suspect you won't have much of a problem.

Comment: do i need to have a common ground for the two PIC?